# Conference Organizing Distribution (COD)

Tags: 7

Is COD shipped as a module or an entire Drupal CMS modified to handle conferencing. I can't find any straight forward documentation installing this to an existing project.

Answer (score 3):

COD is a distribution that you can start a Drupal project with, but you can also take the COD features and implement them into an existing site. It's just easier to start off with COD.

Comment: thanks, for this one project I need to incorporate into  an existing site. Do you know what files I should upload?

Comment: If you download COD, you'll find under profiles/cod/modules/cod_support all of the features for COD. Base is an essential, but then you can grab whatever else you need. You'll probably have to download some dependencies like Commerce, but Drupal can handle that for you.